# repetitive interviewing at large selective tech companies

Tags: interviewing

I've got about 15 years of experience in software engineering, and have worked for a handful of employers at this point. I've done my fair share of interviews at this point as well.  Like many software engineers, I've interviewed with larger companies like Google for potential roles.  I've interviewed there multiple times over the years, and have not received an offer yet.  But about once every 1.5 years they always seem to call me back and I always get curious again.  They no longer have me do the phone screen at this point, just come in for another try.

This last time I had no trouble with any of the questions, but received a flighty response that I "could have answered faster", and a casual dismissal.  My only thought was how I could make my hand write the answers faster next time. The reasoning is usually similar to this, providing little insight, as expected.

At what point does this process fail to be effective anymore?  If they did not offer me a role the last few times, is it likely they will discover something new in the future? Their recruiting system is a bit of a machine, and I wonder if they are more interested in keeping the pipeline full than providing a meaningful interview process to a candidate.  They don't like me enough to hire, but they like me enough to keep interviewing.  As a candidate, is it worthwhile to bother with these large tech company interviews that seem to have odds similar to the lottery, and so many qualified candidates that the selectivity becomes absurd?

Comment: I'm asking the value of repeating no-hire interviews for a large tech company that repeatedly interviews candidates.   Obviously it is my choice, but is there value to it, beyond what can be learned from interviewing for 3 hrs.  I do not get the sense that much thought is put in their end in whether to reopen communication other than I'm in their recruiting system already.   I could replace "Google" with Facebook or Microsoft likely.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe Google thinks that your skills set and your work experience get stronger over time and that makes it worthwhile for them to continue being interested in interviewing you. If you disagree with their calculation and you don't want to play their game, simply say "no" to your Google recruiter the next time they contact you and most likely, they won't bother you. At least this time.

Comment: Exactly what I was going to say. +1